# Laravel 5.4 Relationships between 3 tables

Tags: php, laravel

I am new in laravel, I already know how to join tables using the query builder. I just like to learn how to use relationships to avoid repetition of codes and to simplify it. I can join 2 tables, but I can't get the 3rd table.

I like to display employees assigned tasks information from the `Tasks` table, this table only has the project id that needs to be joined to the `Projects` table. Other employees can join in existing projects with other employees.

`Employee` model:

```
public function tasks()
{
    return $this->hasMany('\App\Task', 'project_coder', 'id');
}
```

`Task` model:

```
public function projects()
{
    return $this->hasMany('\App\Project', 'id', 'project_id');
}
```

`Projects` model:

```
public function belongsToTasks()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('\App\Task', 'project_id', 'id');
}
```

I can only get the IDS from Task model. the ID will be use to fetch the project info from project tables. Unfortunately I cant do that part.

Employees controller:

```
public function show($id)
{
    $data = Employees::find($id);
    return view('show-employee')->withInfo($data);
}
```

Is it good practice to use query builder rather than relationships?

**UPDATE**:

`Employees` table

```
{
    "id":1,
    "name": "Juan"
}
```

`Tasks` table

```
{
    "id":1,    // autoincrement and will not be use for linking to other tables.
    "project_id": 1, //use to connect to project table
    "project_coder": 1 // use to connect to employees table
}
```

`Projects` table

```
{
    "id":1,
    "name": "First Project"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To deal with this is best to create pivot table like `employee_task`
where table will have just two columns `task_id` and `employee_id`

then you can define in Task model

```
public function employees()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('\App\Employee', 'employee_task');
}
```

and Employee model

```
public function tasks()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('\App\Task', 'employee_task');
}
```

now you can see all employee tasks and rest of you relations work just fine

```
$data = Employees::find($id);
$data->tasks //you get all tasks assigned to this employee
$data->tasks()->first()->projects //you get all your projects for first task
$data->tasks()->first()->employees //all employees assigned to first task with this employee
```

Also recommend to you to lookup pivot tables, `attach()`, `detach()` and `sync()` functions. you can check it here : https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#updating-many-to-many-relationships

**UPDATE:**

Ok I understand now what you are trying to do. You already have pivot table. I was little confused with your Project model which is not necessary.

You can remove your `Project` class if you have it just for this relation
and update your model relations as I wrote above. You don't need `project_id` and `project_coder_id` in this relation. Also change the column names to more conventional names like `employee_id` and `task_id` as I mentioned or whatever your table names are.
And you can rename `employee_task` pivot table name to your project table or you can rename it as well.

**EDIT**

When you use Project model for another data, you need to create 4th table as I mentioned above.

**FINAL**

- drop `project_coder` column in `Tasks` table - unecessary column
- create pivot table `employees_task` with `employee_id`,`task_id`
- create mentioned relations with pivot table

I assume that `Project` `hasMany()` tasks and `Task` only `belongsTo()` one project. So need to create these relations as well.

Then you can use these relations like this:

```
$employee = Employee::find($id);
$task = Task::find($id);
$project = Project::find($id);

$employee->tasks //all tasks assigned to employee
$task->employees //all employees assigned to task
$task->project //project info assigned to task
$employee->tasks()->first()->project //project data from first task of employee
$project->tasks()->first()->employees //all employees assigned to first project task
```

Comment: Im not sure If I understand but I already did that part, the Task model has the ID to link with project model. task model has the PROJECT_ID and PROJECT_CODER_ID columns only, that id will be use to fetch the project details from project model. the result is, I can only fetch the ID from task table. the project table is not joining. Also will you suggest to use query builder rather than this relationships? thanks

Comment: I updated my answer. And 3rd table is in this case just mediator, so you won't get any data from that table.

Comment: I updated my post. I need to get the projects table. because it has the information.

Comment: thanks but I really cant get it.What I made is a relationship beween employees and the tasks table which has the IDS to connect in projects table.. then after I get the tasks id, I created another query to get the projects.

Comment: yes but you created only 1:N relationship, between tasks and employess you need M:N

Comment: I solved it my way. btw thanks. I just put hasmany in both employees and task model. then in controller I added ->with('tasks.projects')